# Facebook registration validation: Permission denied to access property 'Arbiter'

Tags: facebook, registration, fbml

I have a problem to validate my Facebook form. On custom input blur, I have the message

> Permission denied to access property

and the validation doesn't occur.

This is my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
    <script src="https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=<?php echo FACEBOOK_APP_ID; ?>&xfbml=1"></script>

    <fb:registration
        fields='[
                {"name":"name"},
                {"name":"first_name"},
                      {"name":"last_name"},
                      {"name":"gender"},
                      {"name":"company", "description":"Company", "type":"text"},
                      {"name":"address", "description":"Address", "type":"text"},
                      {"name":"zip_code", "description":"Zip Code", "type":"text"},
                      {"name":"city", "description":"City", "type":"typeahead", "categories":["city"]},
                      {"name":"phone", "description":"Phone","type":"text"},
                      {"name":"mobile_phone", "description":"Mobile Phone","type":"text"},
                      {"name":"email"},
                      {"name":"optin", "description":"I may receive communications from Fanpage Booster", "type":"checkbox", "default":"unchecked"},
                      {"name":"captcha"}
                     ]'
        redirect-uri="recup.php" width="530" fb_only="true" onvalidate="validate" >
    </fb:registration>
    <script>
        function validate(form) {
            errors = {};
            if (form.company == '') {
                errors.company = "Company can't be empty !";
            }
            if (form.address == '') {
                errors.address = "Address can't be empty !";
            }
            if (form.zip_code == '') {
                errors.zip_code = "Zip Code can't be empty !";
            }
            return errors;
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

I took a look at some tutorials on Facebook registration, at Facebook documentation, and questions on this site, but I don't see solutions or a similar problem ...

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to reproduce that error.  I did have to make sure redirect-uri was set to an absolute URL, add a close html tag, and change the script reference to be protocol less like:

```
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId=APPID&xfbml=1"></script>
```

The Facebook validation doesn't work on blur, it works once the form gets submitted.  Where were you adding an onblur event?

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed the error is the script reference.
Now it works. And i don't bind any events on 'onblur', facebook does that alone.

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same situation and ended up fixing it by using a secure site (HTTPS).
It won't work in HTTP even though I specified a protocol-less script reference.