# Permission denied to access property 'Arbiter' when using HTTPS

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-credits

i am getting below error

Permission denied to access property 'Arbiter'

only when i using application with HTTPS

i already check [Permission denied to access property 'Arbiter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757964/permission-denied-to-access-property-arbiter)

FYI When i write dictly page name in URL as apps.facebook.com/XXXX/YY.aspx then it is working but not with apps.facebook.com/XXXX

but don't have a luck..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using https in redirect_uri solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using same protocol for both iframe and javascript file.

Comment: use [https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js](https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js) if you are using application with https and use [http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js](http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js) if you are using application with http.

Also make sure in your app settings you are using http for "Canvas URL" and https for "Secure Canvas URL"

Comment: Thanks but it is all OK still i a facing this Problem

Comment: FYI When i write dictly page name in URL as https://apps.facebook.com/XXXX/YY.aspx then it is working but not with https://apps.facebook.com/XXXX/