# Changing text of Register button in registration plugin to be 'Next'

Tags: facebook, registration

I used registration plugin of facebook as an intermediate step for my website.. I would like to change the text of 'Register' button to be 'Next' because there will be another step before finalizing registration ..so i used this script to change the text

```
$(document).ready(function()
    {     
    $('#iframeID').load(function(){
        $('#iframeID').contents().find('#fbRegistrationRegisterButtonPrefilled').children('input').val('Next');

    }); 
    });
```

This code can be used only offline (i.e if i saved the page from the browser as a normal html) ..it's not working online and it gives this error "Permission denied to access property 'ownerDocument'"

Is there a way for doing this.. or can this option be available afterwards???

Comment: Related info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757964/permission-denied-to-access-property-arbiter

Answer (score 0):

There's an easier way to do this. All you need to do is put

```
action="Next"
```

as one of the parameters. If you use the **iframe** method then you need to put it inside of the `src=""`, and if you use the **xfbml** method just put it in like any other parameter.