# Facebook canvas iframe resize issue for a particular user

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe, facebook-iframe, facebook-canvas

One user of my app, http://www.beerwhich.com, is experiencing an issue where the iframe does not re-size. For other users and other machines of mine I am unable to reproduce this issue.

Only the user who! is experiencing the problem sees this JavaScript error:

```
error: Permission denied to access property 'Arbiter'
```

Here's a screenshot of the user's canvas iframe clipping the content:

[image]

Has anyone run into this before?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is not uncommon. Here's some examples of other people's issues and what they found to help them out with it:

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=100783

http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?id=100447

[Facebook registration validation: Permission denied to access property 'Arbiter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206587/facebook-registration-validation-permission-denied-to-access-property-arbiter)

[Permission denied to access property 'Arbiter'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8757964/permission-denied-to-access-property-arbiter)